# Boostrap 4 spacing, why doesn't button have vertical space as in version 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-4

***Version 3 layout*** (https://plnkr.co/edit/XDA9EwMAzH4xDSfZaXvS?p=preview)

[image: Bootstrap 3 layout with margin on the button]

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Confirm your details</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel">
          <h4 class="panel-heading">We need to confirm your current address details and contact information.</h4>
          <p class="panel-body">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
      <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Version 4 layout*** (https://plnkr.co/edit/LDy00Kk6eVHDq85ZqjgQ?p=preview)

[image: Bootstrap 4 layout with no margin for the button]

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Confirm your details</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-block">
          <h4 class="card-title">We need to confirm your current address details and contact information.</h4>
          <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
      <p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why doesn't the button have vertical space and how should I add it in Bootstrap v4?

Comment: I have read the documentation, but can't find a clear reason for this change. Adjusting $spacer didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/

Basically, they have added notation for adding margins and padding so that you can add differing amounts depending on the size of the screen. For example, I want to add margin (***'m'***) to the top (***'t'***) of the div for small (***'-sm'***) sized screens. I also want it to be the default spacing (***'-3'***):

```
<div class="mt-sm-3"> <!-- footer nav -->
   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Confirm</a>
</div>
```

Updated plnker: https://plnkr.co/edit/LDy00Kk6eVHDq85ZqjgQ?p=preview

Comment: Be aware: "Avoid margin-top. Vertical margins can collapse, yielding unexpected results." https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/reboot/#approach

Answer (score 0):

According to this link ["Migrating to v4 - Bootstrap 4"](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjX6fLzmobUAhXpI8AKHV09DckQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fv4-alpha.getbootstrap.com%2Fmigration%2F&usg=AFQjCNGIDYiEcM2EjIMO_hUJNPGur3Nanw&sig2=c--zdHSHtryvbCeudKDLWw) Panels have been dropped, it's the Panel that is providing the pseudo HR and a margin/padding below it.

Because it's now using cards, I'm thinking you've lost that extra css formatting and it's just going to be a case of applying margins around the preceding card.

Be aware: "Avoid margin-top. Vertical margins can collapse, yielding unexpected results." [Boostrap Reboot Approach](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/reboot/#approach)